# Comparing a pair of pairs in a list to test for inversion

Tags: python

I have a list like so:

```
["('JAX', 'IAH')", "('IAH', 'ORD')"]  # flight goes JAX -> IAH, then IAH -> Chicago
```

But occasionally I find items like this, which I need to flag / dump:

```
["('JAX', 'IAH')", "('IAH', 'JAX')"]  # flight is an out-and-back --> dump it
```

These only happen when `listlen` = 2 so I have been trying to come up with something clever, but cannot — I've already burned my last brain cell getting 150M records up in Redis this weekend.

Anyone?

Comment: Why are those strings? (Are they actually tuples?)

Comment: Yes, they are tuples.

Comment: `l[0] == l[1][::-1]`?

Comment: minitech, that would (almost) work for literal inversion, but not for logical inversion. 

    >>> xxx[1][::-1]
    ")'XAJ','HAI'("

Comment: So they’re *not tuples*.

Comment: @ToddCurry minitech's solution was based on your answer that they were actual tuples. If they were, then his answer is correct. If instead they're strings then you misled him.

Comment: why not `flight[i][0]==flight[j][1] and flight[i][1]==flight[j][0]` ?  edit: woops I am on my phone and now see they are strings, but you could still implement this with `split`

Comment: minitech -- your solution is the correct one; they *should* have been tuples, and your solution *should* have therefore worked.  I'm not sure why this latest set of results are getting extra quotes around, and therefore not coming in as tuples... More debugging.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invert a tuple with a slice:

```
l[0] == l[1][::-1]
```

If you need to convert the strings into tuples, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("('JAX', 'IAH')")
('JAX', 'IAH')
```